# Expressjs (node) - How to get a set of data which is filtered according to the user

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, express, mongoose

I am new to express js. I am currently building a todo list web app. I have been following the tutorials and is able to perform basic CRUD operation. I have two models.

1. Users - (name, email, password hash, password salt, todo_items - which reference to the second model).
2. Todo_items - (title, description, due_date, user - which reference to the first model).

When a user log in, I am able to read his user_id. However, how can i filter the todo_items that only belongs to the user? My current code looks like this and is returning all the todo_items from all the users.

```
router.get('/api/todo_items', function(req, res, next){
  Todo_items.find(function(err,todo_items){
    if(err){return next(err); }
    res.json(todo_items);
  })
});
```

Currently, I am using a front end framework, Angularjs to filter the results that get displayed. But I thought this is inefficient as the user base gets big. How do I create a filtering system from the backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the collection on the user field, assuming it references the `User` model on the `_id` field so you could have something like the following:

```
router.get('/api/todo_items', function(req, res, next){     
    Guest.find({ "user": user_id }).exec(function(err, todo_items){
        if(err) { return next(err); }
        res.json(todo_items);
    });
});
```

Comment: so i would need a middleware to define the user_id?

Comment: Do you know how i can get the user_id from the local storage?

Comment: You will need a mechanism to get the `user_id` either through middleware via the `req` object `req.user` or use the route url e.g. `router.get('/api/user/:id/todo_items', function(req, res, next){ var user_id = req.params.id; ... }`. Unfortunately that's a broad question which as far as I know would warrant you to create a new question here on SO.